# C++ Polymorphism: Does a virtual function in derived class needs to be declared constant if its declared constant in base class

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I have two classes. In base class A virtual function `window(void)` is declared constant `const` while in derived class B, `window(void)` is not declared as `cont`. Does this satisfy polymorphism? If I call `window()` in main, will it first call the derived class B `window()` first and then class A version of `window()`. In my case it's not doing like this. Should I have to put const at the end of function in derived too?

```
  class A 
  {
   public:
      virtual int window (void) const
      {
         std::cout<<" We are in class A "<<std::endl;
         return std::min(x,y); // x is smaller
      }
    private:
    int x, y;              
   }

  class B : public A 
  {
   public:
       virtual int window (void)
       { 
          std::cout<<" We are in class B "<<std::endl;
          return A::window ();
       }
   }

   void main()
   {
     int z = window();
     std::cout<<z<<std::endl;
   }
```

The output should be like this

```
 We are in class B
 We are in class A
 x
```

Comment: The short answer is "yes" to the question in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of an overriding method must exactly match the signature of the virtual base method that it is overriding (well, except for the case of covariant return values, but that is not relevant to your question).  That signature includes trailing `const`ness.  So yes, if the base method is declared as `const`, the overriding method must be declared as `const` as well.

If you are using C++11 or later, you should mark an overriding method with the [`override` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override), then the compiler will validate that it is actually overriding a virtual base method of *matching signature*, and will generate an error if a matching base method is not found.  You don't get that validation at compile-time if you omit the `override` specifier.